# Extract patches from matrix / copy on write

Tags: r

I have a fairly large (1040x1392) matrix of doubles and I would like to extract another matrix whose columns are the 16x16 patches of the first matrix. (I know, it is a lot of data and it may not be practical to use it, but this should work...)

I tried using this code, where 'data' is the original matrix:

```
# Create a matrix of starting coordinates for each patch
patch.size = 16
patch.inc = patch.size - 1
coords = expand.grid(x=1:(ncol(data)-patch.inc), y=1:(nrow(data)-patch.inc))
coords = as.matrix(coords)

# Pre-allocate the destination matrix
patches = double(nrow(coords)*patch.size^2)
dim(patches) = c(patch.size^2, nrow(coords))

#Create overlapping patches
for (i in 1:nrow(coords))
{
  x=coords[i,1]
  y=coords[i,2]
  patches[,i] = as.vector(data[y:(y+patch.inc), x:(x+patch.inc)])
}
```

This runs impossibly slowly on a reasonably fast Win7-64 machine with 8GB of RAM; even creating just 100 patches is slow.

It turns out that the assignment to patches[,i] is the problem. Looking at Task Manager, there is a huge spike in memory use when I assign to patches[,i].

I have a couple of questions. First, what is going on? It looks like the whole patches matrix is being copied on each assignment. Is that right? If so, why? I thought that pre-allocating the patches matrix would avoid that. Second, is there a better way to write this code so it might complete within my lifetime :-) ?

Thanks! Kent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 2nd question, here's a solution using `lapply`.

You could transpose the result `out` if you want the exact output as your script. I checked with smaller dimensions and verified that its equal to your output `patches`.

```
set.seed(1234)
nr <- 1040
nc <- 1392
data <- matrix(rnorm(nr*nc), nrow = nr)
patch.size <- 16
idx <- expand.grid(1:(ncol(data)-patch.size+1), 1:(nrow(data)-patch.size+1))
idx[,3] <- idx[,1]+patch.size-1
idx[,4] <- idx[,2]+patch.size-1
idx <- as.matrix(idx)

# using rbenchmark
require(rbenchmark)
myFun <- function() {
    out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(idx), 
        function(tx) c(data[idx[tx,2]:idx[tx,4], idx[tx,1]:idx[tx,3]])))
}
benchmark(myFun(), replications = 2)

# Result:
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 myFun()            2 152.146        1   147.957    4.184          0         0

# using system.time
system.time(out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(idx), 
        function(tx) c(data[idx[tx,2]:idx[tx,4], idx[tx,1]:idx[tx,3]]))))        

# Result
  user  system elapsed 
58.852   1.784  60.638
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! I'm still curious about the first question if anyone has any thoughts...